# Need a way to write headers on a wav file generated by sox

Tags: audio, wav, command-line-interface

I'm using sox to convert some mp3 files to wav for a project. The problem is that the software that plays the files does not have the media name for the element it is playing. I can't seem to find a win32 cli tool to read the header of the wav file and write what I need to it.

Sox will read the header but it's not showing the title of the media element that was inserted with the old software I used. I just couldnt automate it or I would have used it instead.

I have determined the info is written in either CART CHUNK section or just to the file headers. I can't figure out to write my own data there.

Comment: There is no media name in a WAV header. Are you trying to extract the ID3 data and carry the name information along to the WAV file?

Comment: I checked the id3 for the existing way to do what I'm doing with sox and there is no id3 info on the file. I'm not sure how the playing software knows what its playing. I do know that when I take the two files and put them in the old converting software it reads as riffpcm for the one made with sox and a different one for the one done the old way.

Comment: Also the file sizes are exactly the same.

Comment: I have determined the file name is just written in the header its not an id3 tag on the file or anything.

Comment: And where are you expecting it should go in the WAV file? There is no place for a title string in a WAV header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to do this was with this project: https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3